# Error ILT0005 during compilation with .NET Native tool chain

Tags: win-universal-app, .net-native

Even the default template of Universal Windows app cannot be compiled with .NET Native tool chain. Is the comparator broken?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you upgrade to Windows 10 double check that you profile folder in C:\Users does not contain any non-ASCII characters. If it does then .NET Native tool chain will not work for you.

Comment: Report bugs at connect.microsoft.com so they get fixed.

Comment: @HansPassant can we vote for this? i.e. link please?